# iOS 7 - UIPopoverController : deprecated arrows?

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm adapting my app to iOS 7 and while I was reading the documentation, I read this line, under popoverArrowDirection at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> "(Deprecated. Popovers do not use arrows in iOS 7 and later.)"

This is weird, since my popover seems to still have arrows in iOS 7. Am I just understanding this the wrong way?

Comment: Apparently that comment is not there anymore =D. In fact, if you go to the last page of the document, you can see the following release note: "2013-12-16 Removed incorrect deprecation information on popoverArrowDirection."

Comment: Great! Maybe the bug report I filed made a difference. Thanks for the update. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the documentation. Arrows were probably on the chopping block by designers but the decision was reverted in usability testing.

If you look in `UIPopoverController.h`, you don't see any deprecation attributes (e.g. `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS` or `NS_DEPRECATED_IOS`):

```
/* Returns the direction the arrow is pointing on a presented popover. Before 
   presentation, this returns UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown.
 */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIPopoverArrowDirection popoverArrowDirection;
```

Contrast this with `-[NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:]`:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:");
```

These attributes are important because they generated the compiler warnings and errors.  They are also maintained by the people who actually code the UI.

Combining the lack of attributes with the fact that the behavior you see directly contradicts the documentation, you really shouldn't worry about it.  If it really bothers you, can [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Hi Brian, indeed, it is not deprecated in the source code. Nevertheless, I'd like to know if someone heard anything more than that so I know if I continue to incorporate popovers with arrows in my designs. Thanks for digging in the code!

Comment: @airpaulg, you could also file a bug report for the wrong documentation at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Good idea Felipe! At first, I didn't see it as a bug, but this might be appropriate now.

Comment: The headers are really the best source for what's deprecated or not. They are maintained by the people who coded the arrows and the compiler uses the headers to generate warnings or errors.  Updated my answer to expand on it more and included @FelipeCypriano's link to file a bug report.